# jquery function for check box issue

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, struts-1

I have a data table which contains a checkbox column and also uses pagination.When i check some checkboxes in the first page and navigate to the second page and check another one in the second page,The options i checked in the first page is not retained there.if i declare the array inside the function.
code is 
     $(function () {

```
  $("input[name='partialChkNm']").click(function () {

      var chkboxList = new Array();

    if ($("'input[name='partialChkNm']:checked'").length) {
        ;

      $("'input[name='partialChkNm']:checked'").each(function () {

          chkboxList += $(this).val() + ",";
      });
      chkboxList = chkboxList.slice(0, -1);//remove last comma value

    }
    else {
      alert('Nothing Selected');
    }
  });

});
```

but if i declare the same array outside of the function it retain the value but while checking and unchecking it does not remove the value and it also appends its own value,like
code is

```
 var chkboxList = new Array();
 $(function () {

  $("input[name='partialChkNm']").click(function () {


    if ($("'input[name='partialChkNm']:checked'").length) {

      $("'input[name='partialChkNm']:checked'").each(function () {

          chkboxList += $(this).val() + ",";
      });
      chkboxList = chkboxList.slice(0, -1);//remove last comma value

    }
    else {
      alert('Nothing Selected');
    }
  });

});
```

if i have 5 checkbox on first page and its contains some value like

1 value 100/a,
2 value 200/b,
3 value 300/c,
4 value 400/d,
5 value 500/f

if i selected two checkbox value and inspect the array, i am getting value like
**200/b200/b,400/d**
array appends the first value again while checking second check box and its acting the same while unchecking the any of selected checkbox.

Please Help :(

Comment: Why making it so difficult just add event to checkbox checkedchanged, if the checkbox is checked add it to array and unchecked and exists in array then remove it

Comment: i am doing the same as you sugegsted

Comment: $("'input[name='partialChkNm']:checked'").each(function () {

          chkboxList += $(this).val() + ",";
      }); In this code first make chkboxList  = ""; i.e. empty.

Comment: Also I am not sure while doing paging are you still getting all thec checked check boxes else while doing paging please do not clear the array, but do clear if you are on the same page and use checks or unchecks any of the check box.

Comment: @GirishSakhare thanks for the  suggestion but its not working :(